# Splitting a string few characters after the delimiter

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I have a large data set of names and states that I need to split. After splitting, I want to create new rows with each name and state. My data strings are in multiple lines that look like this

```
"Peter Johnson, IN Chet Charles, TX Ed Walsh, AZ"
"Ralph Hogan, TX, Michael Johnson, FL"
```

I need the data to look like this

```
attr      name            state
1         Peter Johnson   IN
2         Chet Charles    TX
3         Ed Walsh        AZ
4         Ralph Hogan     TX
5         Michael Johnson FL
```

I can't figure out how to do this, perhaps split it somehow a few characters after the comma? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a single string in one line or multiple lines as showed

Comment: fun with google: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-data-import-tutorial#gs.jJEJxXY

Comment: The input is unclear. Is it a single string in quotes?

Comment: thanks, my data is in multiple lines.

Answer (score -1):

If it is multiple line strings, then we can create a delimiter with `gsub`, split the strings using `strsplit`, create `data.frame` with the components of the `split` in the output `list`, and `rbind` it together.

```
d1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(gsub("([A-Z]{2})(\\s+|,)",
                    "\\1;", lines), "[,;]"), function(x) {
                        x1 <- trimws(x)
       data.frame(name = x1[c(TRUE, FALSE)],state = x1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]) }))     
cbind(attr = seq_len(nrow(d1)), d1)
#  attr            name state
#1    1   Peter Johnson    IN
#2    2    Chet Charles    TX
#3    3        Ed Walsh    AZ
#4    4     Ralph Hogan    TX
#5    5 Michael Johnson    FL
```

---

Or this can be done in a compact way

```
library(data.table)
fread(paste(gsub("([A-Z]{2})(\\s+|,)", "\\1\n", lines), collapse="\n"),
        col.names = c("names", "state"), header = FALSE)[, attr := 1:.N][]
#             names state attr
#1:   Peter Johnson    IN    1
#2:    Chet Charles    TX    2
#3:        Ed Walsh    AZ    3
#4:     Ralph Hogan    TX    4
#5: Michael Johnson    FL    5
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection("Peter Johnson, IN Chet Charles, TX Ed Walsh, AZ
 Ralph Hogan, TX, Michael Johnson, FL"))
```